# Insert multiple record into one model with condition ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to insert multiple record into database with loop, it's really pain for me when insert bills record for each room in used. So my goal is to create bill for all rooms in used `TRANGTHAI == 1` by using form.

Here's my controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(HOADON hoadon)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            dynamic listPhong = (from p in db.PHONGs where p.TRANGTHAI == 1 select p.ID_PHONG).ToList();
            foreach (var phong in listPhong)
            {
                hoadon = new HOADON()
                {
                    ID_PHONG = phong.ID_PHONG, // cant get ID here
                    ID_DONGIA = 1,
                    TRANGTHAI = "Chua dong tien" // status = "Not paid"
                    ID_CANBO = int.Parse(Session["ID"].ToString()) // get ID manager who creates this bill
                };
                db.HOADONs.Add(hoadon);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
            return View(hoadon);
    }
```

I keep the month and year in the `Create.cshtml` so manager just need to type 2 of them and the rest is auto generated.

If I put`ID_PHONG = 1` in controller, it works but get the data of current room that has `ID_PHONG = 1`.

When I put `ID_PHONG = phong.ID_PHONG` (code suggestion doesn't suggest to me) and run the project, it throws `Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: ''int' does not contain a definition for 'ID_PHONG''` and `This exception was originally thrown at this call stack: HoaDon02.Controllers.HOADONsController.Create(HoaDon02.Models.HOADON) in HOADONsController.cs [External Code]`

I also tried put these two model into view model (get, set) and call it like this

```
 public ActionResult Create(ViewModel_HoaDon vm)
    {

        var id_phong = (vm.Phong.ID_PHONG);
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            dynamic listPhong = (from p in id_phong where p.TRANGTHAI == 1 select p.ID_PHONG).ToList(); // red line in id_phong and where.
            foreach (var phong in listPhong)
            {
                HOADON data = new HOADON()
                {
                    ID_PHONG = phong.ID_PHONG,
                    ID_DONGIA = 1,
                    THANG = 1,
                    NAM = DateTime.Now.Year,
                    ID_CANBO = int.Parse(Session["ID"].ToString())
                };
                db.HOADONs.Add(data);
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(vm);
    }
```

The error it throws is: `Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'int'. 'Where' not found.`

Please let me know if you have solutions.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: In the first code, change `dynamic listPhong` to `List<int> listPhong` and change `ID_PHONG = phong.ID_PHONG` to `ID_PHONG = phong`.

Comment: For second code, I doubt that `id_phong` is just `int`, but not `IEnumerable` type, so it doesn't support for `.Where()`.

Comment: Holy crap IT WORKS. THANKS A LOT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Chetan, I have two solution for this. You can use `dynamic` or `List<int>`
and in

```
HOADON data = new HOADON()
            {
                ID_PHONG = phong.ID_PHONG,
                ID_DONGIA = 1,
                THANG = 1,
                NAM = DateTime.Now.Year,
                ID_CANBO = int.Parse(Session["ID"].ToString())
            };
```

you just simplify to `ID_PHONG = phong`

Comment: It is not magic. As you are creating `listPhong`, you are already extracting the `ID_PHONG` property (`select p.ID_PHONG`). Inside your foreach loop, `phong` is in fact `p.ID_PHONG` (i.e. an `int`, not a `Phong`). Hence, when trying to assign `ID_PHONG = phong.ID_PHONG`, you are actually trying to assign `p.ID_PHONG.ID_PHONG`. A more appropriate name for the `phong` variable in your foreach loop would be `phongId`.

Comment: Indeed, how could I miss that.